# Programmatically set Windows Live Messenger Display Picture

Tags: avatar, windows-live-messenger

How can I programmatically set Windows Live Messenger (currently using 8.5.1302.1018) display picture. Possible solutions can be in C++, .NET or VB. Even just a hint could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source project called [MSNP-Sharp](http://code.google.com/p/msnp-sharp/) that you should look at.

You can use this to connect to MSN and set your profile picture. Here's an example of setting the image:

```
        try
        {
            Image fileImage = Image.FromFile(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ImageFileName"]);
            DisplayImage displayImage = new DisplayImage();
            displayImage.Image = fileImage;
            m_Messenger.Owner.DisplayImage = displayImage;
            m_Messenger.Nameserver.StorageService.UpdateProfile(fileImage, "MyPhoto");
        }
        catch
        {
            LogError(new StackTrace(true), "Error adding avatar image.");
        }
```